# Bootstrap 4 full-screen modal with carousel issues in Safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, safari

This is my attempt at creating a **full-screen** Bootstrap 4 modal with a **full-screen** images carousel.

Images have `max-height: 100%;` and `max-width: 100%;` so they are always fully visible, and they are vertically and horizontally centered.

It works on Chrome and Firefox, but for some reason, doesn't work on Safari (Version 12.1.2 (14607.3.9) on mac os).

**Images aren't displayed and seem to have no size on Safari.** I can't figure out why...

```css
.modal-full {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.modal-full .modal-dialog {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.modal-full .modal-content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.modal-full .modal-content .modal-body {
  padding: 0;
}
.modal-full .modal-content .carousel {
  height: 100%;
}
.modal-full .modal-content .carousel-actions {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.modal-full .modal-content .carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}
.modal-full .modal-content .carousel-inner > .carousel-item {
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.modal-full .modal-content .carousel-inner > .carousel-item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="#" class="gallery-to-carousel btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal">
  Open modal
</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal modal-full fade" id="portfolioModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="portfolioModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-body">

        <div id="portfolioCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
        
          <div class="carousel-inner">

              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x800">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x800">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/2000x400">
              </div>
              
          </div>

          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#portfolioCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#portfolioCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/t9kwdeur/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your `.carousel` to `height: 100vh;` from `100%` seems to work in Safari

```
.modal-full .modal-content .carousel {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nqk0935s/)

**Or** you could add a `height: 100%;` to the `.carousel`'s parent - `.modal-body`.

```
.modal-full .modal-content .modal-body {
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[Updated fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/qarof09t/)